# Number of bytes having 3 bits that are 1

Tags: probability

How to calculate:

- number of bytes having exactly 3 bits that are 1
- number of bytes having at least 3 bits that are 1
- number of bytes having no more then 3 bits that are 1

Comment: Strictly speaking, you cannot say anything without assume a probability distribution

Comment: Probability?  There is no probability in this question.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**: For the first one, how many ways can you put $3$ ones into a string of length $8$? The rest of those $5$ bits must be $0$. (this may help if you don't know combinations or permutations: https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html )

For the second, break it up into cases of how many ways to place exactly $3$, how many ways to place exactly $4$, etc. or think of it more cleverly.

For three, it's also very similar. We can have either exactly $0$, exactly $1$, exactly $2$, or exactly $3$ ones.

Comment: answer for the first one will be 24? 8*3?

Comment: 8*3+8*2+8*1=48 for the third one?

Comment: How did you get that? There are $8$ slots and you need to put exactly $3$ ones into those eight slots. So, read the link I put there and it should be $\binom{8}{3}\cdot\binom{5}{5}=\frac{8!}{3!(8-3)!}\cdot\frac{5!}{5!(5-5)!}=\frac{8\cdot7\cdot6}{3\cdot2\cdot1}\cdot1=8\cdot7=56$. It's similar for the second problem

Comment: Are you sure? There are 256 combinations in total and 56 of them are having exactly 3 ones?

Comment: Yes. For a "check", we know that the number of strings with exactly $0$ ones plus the number with exactly $1$ ones, plus ... all strings with exactly $8$ ones should be all strings (256 of them). This is just (by the same logic as my previous comment) $$\binom{8}{0}+\binom{8}{1}+\binom{8}{2}+\binom{8}{3}+\binom{8}{4}+\binom{8}{5}+\binom{8}{6}+\binom{8}{7}+\binom{8}{8}=1+8+28+56+70+56+28+8+1=256$$

Comment: That explained a lot. Thanks for all your time.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.